# Format PivotTable values

Tags: excel, pivot-table

The report filter values on my PivotTable has decimal values. The source data for my PivotTable has these values as a percentage field.

How do I change it back to percentage field on the report filter?

I tried format cells and field settings options on the report filter but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

In the PivotTable right click on the value field:
[image]

Then click on *Number Format* and choose *Percentage*.